# How can I change column data type from float to string in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to get a column in a dataframe form float to string. I have tried

```
df = readtable("data.csv", coltypes = {String, String, String, String, String, Float64, Float64, String});
```

but I got complained

```
syntax: { } vector syntax is discontinued
```

I also have tried

```
dfB[:serial] = string(dfB[:serial])
```

but it didn't work either. So, I'd like to know what would be the proper approach to change column data type in Julia.

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your first attempt, Julia tells you what the problem is - you can't make a vector with `{}`, you need to use `[]`. Also, the name of the keyword argument should be `eltypes` rather than `coltypes`.

On the second try, you don't have a float, you have a Vector of floats. So to change the type you need to change the type of all elements. In Julia, elementwise operations on vectors are generalized by the 'dot' syntax, e.g. `string.(collect(dfB[:serial]))` . The `collect` is needed currently to cast the DataArray to a normal Array first – this will fail if the DataArray contains NAs. IMHO the DataFrames interface is still rather wonky, so expect a few headaches like this ATM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, neither of them works in my case. The first proposed solution raised "MethodError: no method matching readtable(::String; coltypes=DataType[String,String,String,String,String,Float64,Float64,String])" and the second one showed "MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int64
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Int64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.". Any thought why?

Comment: The `string.(x)` call should definitely not raise that exception. Seems like you're trying to convert from `String` to `Int` and not the other way around. Can you show the code that you ran? Maybe a demo dataset?

Comment: It does cause that error, sorry. That's weird.
A workaround currently is `string.(collect(df[:serial]))` which converts a DataArray to an Array before converting to String.

Comment: untested - but @bensw it should at least be `eltypes` not `coltypes`

Comment: @Michael K. Borregaard  `string.(collect(df[:serial]))` does work. `eltypes` does work as well with `[]` but not  with `{}`. can you also update your first attempt solution? I will mark your answer as correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @niczky12 it is as simple as that. `df = readtable("data.csv"); df[:serial] = string(df[:serial]);`