# Converting column type from String to Int in a DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to change column datatype in Julia from string to int but no luck so far. Neither `convert()` nor `parse()` works. Is there any way to do that?

I have tried these but none works

`df[:serial] = int.(collect(df[:strSerial]))
 df[:serial] = map(x->parse(Int,x),df[:strSerial])
 df[:serial] = Int64(df[:strSerial])`

Comment: What is difference between this and [How can I change column data type from float to string in Julia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605432/how-can-i-change-column-data-type-from-float-to-string-in-julia?)

Comment: @Atomic_alarm the difference is the same style of syntax does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parse()` should work:

```
df = DataFrame(
  yearsAsString = ["2016", "2017", "2018"] 
)
df[:years] = [parse(Int,x) for x in df[:yearsAsString]] 

df

3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ yearsAsString │ years │
├─────┼───────────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ "2016"        │ 2016  │
│ 2   │ "2017"        │ 2017  │
│ 3   │ "2018"        │ 2018  │
```

(remember to use `Int` with the capital I)

**Edited** (thanks MattB)

In current Julia 0.5.1 (and 0.6 alpha) this works too:

```
df[:y2] = parse.([Int],df[:yearsAsString])
```

In Julia 0.6 only:

```
df[:y2] = parse.(Int,df[:yearsAsString])
```

Comment: I would love to have an overloaded parse function, e.g. `df[:x2] = parse(Int,df[:x])`

Comment: @Antonello - on Julia 0.6 you can use dot-broadcasting: `parse.(Int, df[:x])`.

Comment: @MattB. thank you.  `df[:y2] = parse.(Int, df[:yearsAsString])` is actually equivalent to `df[:y3] = broadcast(x -> parse(Int,x), df[:yearsAsString] )`. No problems in the upcoming julia 0.6. In 0.5 the explicit `bradcast` form should be already available, but there it rises a MethodError "Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type String". Why ?